# Decoding JSON: 'InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Here is an example of the JSON I would like to decode:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "affenpinscher": [],
    "african": [],
    "airedale": [],
    "akita": [],
    "appenzeller": [],
    "australian": ["shepherd"],
    "basenji": [],
    "beagle": [],
    "bluetick": [],
    "borzoi": [],
    "bouvier": [],
    "boxer": [],
    "brabancon": [],
    "briard": [],
    "buhund": ["norwegian"]
  }
}
```

I have my model set up like this:

```
class JsonResponse {
   final List<String> breeds;

   JsonResponse(this.breeds);

    factory JsonResponse.fromJson(Map<String, List<String>> json) {
    return JsonResponse(json["message"]!);
  }
}
```

This gives me the error: `InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The key `message` is not of type `List<String>` as required by the class `JsonResponse `. So when the class is constructed by the factory it throws the type error it says. 
You would have to convert the value to a List for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type in your `JsonResponse` is ingoring the JSON scheme of the data your receiving.

From the sample JSON you sent, the types are:

```
object {
  "message": object {
    "type": [ string ]
  }
}
```

Which would translate to Dart's:

```dart
class JsonResponse {
   final Map<String, dynamic> message;

   JsonResponse(this.message);

    factory JsonResponse.fromJson(Map<String, List<String>> json) {
    return JsonResponse(json["message"]!);
  }
}
```

The way you can access these lists is the following:

```dart
final JsonResponse response; // Fetch your response.

response.message['buhund']; // This is your List<String>.
```